# How do I solve $\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac {\ln(e^x-1)}{x} $?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

My only problem is the $\infty$ because otherwise it's a special limit. Do I use substitution? 
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac {\ln(e^x-1)}{x} $$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways that you could go about this; many people will suggest you use L'Hopital's rule.  But, that ignores the intuition here, so let's try it a little differently.

Intuitively: when $x$ is large, $e^x-1$ is approximately $e^x$, so that $\ln(e^x-1)$ is approximately $\ln(e^x)=x$. So, we should expect this limit to approach $1$.

Let's try to codify this intuition.  You could start by writing
$$
e^x-1=e^x\cdot\frac{e^x-1}{e^x}=e^x\left(1-e^{-x}\right).
$$
Then, using the properties of the logarithm,
$$
\ln(e^x-1)=\ln(e^x)+\ln(1-e^{-x})=x+\ln(1-e^{-x}).
$$
Substituting this into the expression, we get
$$
\frac{\ln(e^x-1)}{x}=\frac{x+\ln(1-e^{-x})}{x}=1+\frac{\ln(1-e^{-x})}{x}.
$$
The limit of this latter term as $x\to\infty$ is easily computed.

Comment: Thank you! Feeling silly now.. ahah

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\ln(e^x-1)=\ln(e^x)+\ln(1-e^{-x})=x+\ln(1-e^{-x})$$

Now $\lim_{x\to\infty}=\ln(1-e^{-x})=\ln1=?$

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ goes to $\infty$, then we can assume that $x>1$. Since $e^x -1 \le e^x$ and $\ln x$ increases, we can know that
$$
\ln(e^x -1 ) \le \ln e^x =x.
$$
Since $0<e^x - 2^x< e^x-1$,
$$
\ln(e^x-2^x)\le \ln(e^x-1).
$$
Thus this inequality holds:
$$
1+\frac{\ln\left(1-\frac{2}{e}\right)}{x}\le\frac{\ln(e^x-2^x)}{x} \le \frac{\ln(e^x-1)}{x}\le 1.
$$
Since $\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{\ln\left(1-\frac{2}{e}\right)}{x}\right)=1$,
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln(e^x-1)}{x}=1
$$
by sandwich theorem.

Comment: I was always told that it was called the squeeze theorem, but sandwich theorem sounds tastier.

Answer (score 0):

You estimate that 
$$
\ln(e^x-1) \approx \ln(e^x) = x
$$
especially for large $x$ and thus this limit goes towards $1$.

More formally you could try L'Hôspital's rule, as this is a limit of type $\infty / \infty$.

Comment: I am a 12-th grade student from Portugal, and here they don't teach us L'Hôpital's rule...
Thanks

Comment: Do you have a formal definition of limits? What is in your toolbox?

Comment: Hey, I just noticed the crazy tag. :-)

Comment: It's easy to miss :-)